# Adding Pollfish And PrintIO in One app having duplicate issue

Tags: ios

In My App we need to add Following SDKs:

- Pollfish
- PrintIO

But I face a following

```
duplicate symbol _VERSION in:
 /MyAppPath/Library/PrintIO/PrintIO.framework/PrintIO(BTEncryption.o)
 /MyAppPath/pollfish.framework/pollfish ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

Both are frameworks.

If I remove one framework then My app works fine. But I need to add both things.